# llenado de una tabla desde otra base de datos

Tags: postgresql

estoy tratando de llenar una tabla con información de otra de otra base de datos, pero me da este error

```
cross-database references are not implemented:
```

el codigo que utilizopara realiar el copiado es este

```
insert into sigestel.public.estado (select * from dblink('centauro.public.estado'))
```

Comment: ¿qué pasa si utilizas `insert into public.estado (select * from dblink('public.estado'))`  o `insert into public.estado (select * from dblink('connection options...', 'public.estado'))`. Lo que no se puede hacer, creo, es poner el nombre de la base de datos prefijando los nombres de esquemas y tablas

Comment: me da este error "ERROR:  function dblink(unknown) does not exist"

Comment: en el siguiente post la mejor respuesta sirve para tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172473/hacer-un-select-entre-dos-base-de-datos-en-un-mismo-servidor-postgresql
Saludos.

Comment: excelente este post me ayudo mucho

Answer (score 0):

La forma de clonar una tabla de una base en otra base es:
SELECT * INTO BaseDestino.dbo.TablaACopiar FROM BaseOrigen.dbo.TablaACopiar