# Hacer un SELECT entre dos base de datos en un mismo servidor

Tags: postgresql

Estoy intentando hacer un select entre dos base de datos distintas que están en el mismo servidor; esta es la consulta que hago:

```
SELECT A.nodo, 
       B.nodo
FROM   camper.public.camper1 A 
       INNER JOIN camper_tmp.public.campi2c B 
               ON A.nodo= B.nodo
```

y este es el resultado:

> Error de SQL:
>
> ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented:
> "camper_tmp.public.campi2c" LINE 4:        INNER JOIN
> camper_tmp.public.campi2c B

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal, o cómo puedo hacer ese select entre dos base de datos diferentes en postgres?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para hacer una consulta entre 2 o más bases de datos en postgresql debes usar **dblink**, suponiendo que tienes 2 bases de datos; `test1` y `test2` que contienen las tablas `tabla1` y `tabla2` respectivamente sigue los siguientes pasos:

**1.** Asegurate de que exista el archivo **dblink.sql** donde instalaste el PostgreSQL, por ejemplo:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\share\extension\

De no existir puedes descargarla o instalarla, existen muchos enlaces que indican como hacerlo dependiendo el sistema operativo y la versión.

**2.** Debes tener el nombre de la base de datos, el nombre de usuario y la contraseña para poder acceder, por ejemplo:

```
Base de datos: tabla2
usuario: postgres
password: 123456
```

**3.** Suponiendo que te encuentras en la base de datos `test1`, coloca la siguiente linea:

```
create extension dblink;
```

**4.** Por ultimo realiza la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
select T1.campo1, T1.campo2..., T2.campo1, T2.campo2, ... 
from tabla1 T1, dblink('dbname=test2 user=postgres password=123456', 'select * from tabla2') as T2 (campo1 tipo1, campo2 tipo2, ...)
where condiciones
```

Ademas de los datos de la bd, en campo1, campo2, etc debes colocar el alias que tendrán los campos, y en tipo1, tipo2, etc, debes colocar el tipo (int, varchar, etc.)

Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Mi estimado gracias por responder, recien lo veo cuando ya lo habia hecho con posgresql-wdf , a un asi probare con el db link a ver con cual de los 2 me quedo, un gusto.

Comment: @IsraelCorreaQuevedo Yo estoy intentando lo mismo que tu, pero una de la base de datos  se almacena en la memoria interna y otra en una tarjeta microSD. ¿Cómo enlazas exactamente ambas bases de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Hoy tuve este problema, y encontré otra solución:

Postgresql tiene un módulo llamado **postgres_fdw**, el que puede ser utilizado para acceder a datos que se encuentran en una BD externa, ya sea dentro o fuera del mismo servidor.
[Documentación oficial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html)

Para poder realizar esta tarea, el usuario de la BD debe ser super usuario.
Si el postgresql está instalado en Linux, puede ingresar con usuario *postgres* al `psql` de la siguiente manera:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Y para asignar el permiso, es así:

```
alter role nombre_usuario superuser
```

Volviendo a la BD, en la misma ventana que usted escribe la query escribimos lo siguiente:

- Crear la extensión para ocupar el módulo

  ```
  create extension postgres_fdw
  ```
- Crear el servidor foráneo. Crea como un espacio donde vamos a poner la ruta al servidor que queremos consultar y no estamos llegando.

  ```
  create server myserver FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host '127.0.0.1', dbname 'nombre_bdd', port '5432');
  ```
- Vamos a darle las "atribuciones" al usuario de la bd, para que pueda acceder al server que hemos creado en la línea anterior

  ```
  create user mapping for nombre_usuario SERVER myserver OPTIONS (user 'nombre_usuario', password 'la_clave');
  ```
- Crear una tabla, dentro del servidor que acabamos de crear, que será exactamente igual a la tabla que queremos consultar. Tendrá el mismo nombre y los mismos campos.

  ```
  create foreign table nombre_tabla (id bigint NOT NULL,
  nombre character varying(80))
  server myserver
  ```

Con estos pasos hemos conseguido tener acceso a una tabla en otro servidor, que podremos consultar desde el nuestro.

La query ahora debería ser algo así como:

```
select mi_tabla.campo1, tabla_externa.campo2 
from mi tabla
inner join tabla_externa on mi_tabla.id_tabla_externa=tabla_externa.id
```