# Función para insertar datos desde una BD a otra BD

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

de ante mano muchas gracias... me encuentro realizando un sistema  `PHP` que obtiene datos desde `Moodle` y me gustaría realizar una función en el mismo `pgsql` de `Moodle` que cumpla una condición donde si aprueba el examen se inserte esa informacion en la `BD` de mi aplicativo `PHP` seria algo como: `select usuario,nota from user where nota > 7` y esos dos valores en un `insert` esto seria cada vez que un alumno apruebe así que debería ir en un `trigger`. la `funcion` y el `trigger` lo podria hacer sin problemas pero llevar esos datos a otra `BD` solo lo he hecho en `MySql` he leído a cerca de esto y he visto que necesito varias extensiones como lo explican [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172473/hacer-un-select-entre-dos-base-de-datos-en-un-mismo-servidor-postgresql) o [aquí](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/958993320808201927j3bac2eect3a0490eca7d5647f%40mail.gmail.com) pero estos ejemplos no han tenido condiciones y estoy trabajando con el `docker` de `postgres` y la verdad me he complicado, espero puedan darme un ejemplo con mi caso y nuevamente gracias, Saludos!

Comment: Hola Gilberto. Sinceramente, no entiendo muy bien el problema. Puedes explicarte mejor porfavor? Creo que lo que quieres es hacer un `insert` en BD1 con datos de BD2. No es asi?

Comment: exacto , pero que cumpla una condición antes de insertarse