# ¿Como hacer un inner join entre dos bases de datos distintas en pgadmin4?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Como lo mencione en el titulo, ¿como puedo realiza un `inner join` entre dos bases de datos distintas en `posgresql` con `pgadmin4`?, mi información es la siguiente:

Base de datos 1

```
Escuela
```

Tabla

```
Alumnos
```

Campos

```
Nombre_Alumno
Curp_Alumno
Grupo_Alumno
Nombre_Docente
```

Base de datos 2

```
Personal
```

Tabla

```
Docente
```

Campos

```
Nombre_Docente
Rfc_Docente
Curp_Docente
```

Lo que yo quiero es hacer un `inner join`, utilizando el nombre del docente y me traiga toda la informacion de la base de datos personal, muchas gracias :)

Yo lo andaba haciendo de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT * FROM "Alumnos" INNER JOIN "Personal.dbo.Docente" ON "Nombre_docente"="Nombre_docente" order by "Nombre_docente";
```

Comment: Qué versión de PostgreSQL usas? `dbo` suena a SQL Server. Lo que necesitas es crear un `FOREIGN SERVER`, a menos que me haya perdido algo nuevo en las versiones más recientes.

Comment: Tal vez te sirva revisar [Hacer un SELECT entre dos base de datos en un mismo servidor - postgresql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172485/77879)

Comment: Un foreign server es la solución. Los dblink son funciones viejas y no se recomienda su uso; los foreign servers están soportados y han mejorado su desempeño en versiones recientes

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que uses FDW en vez de dblink, pues los FDW tienen mejores beneficios respecto a los dblink, puedes ver la doc aquí  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/postgres-fdw.html

un ejemplo de su uso con tus datos:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
--acceso al servidor
CREATE SERVER foreign_server
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
    OPTIONS (host 'IP_de_tu_server', port '5432', dbname 'Personal');
--usuario para conectarte
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR public
    SERVER foreign_server
    OPTIONS (user 'tu_usuario', password 'tu_password');
--definicion de la tabla que va a apuntar a la tabla de la otra BD

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE f_docente (
    Nombre_Docente text,
    Rfc_Docente text,
    Curp_Docente text)
    SERVER foreign_server
    OPTIONS (schema_name 'esquema', table_name 'docente');
```

despues puedes hacer tu query del siguinete modo:

```
SELECT * FROM "Alumnos" INNER JOIN "f_docente" ON "Alumnos"."Nombre_docente"="f_docente".nombre_docente order by "Nombre_docente";
```

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas instalar `dblink`, para poder hacer consultas multibase en `PostgreSql`... En **algunas versiones** he podido hacerlo solo creando esta función:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.dblink(
    text,
    text)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
'$libdir/dblink', 'dblink_record'
  LANGUAGE c VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 1
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION public.dblink(text, text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Una vez que tengas instalado dblink o creado la función (si la función no sirve instala todo dblink), entonces haces tu consulta de esta manera:

```
select * 
from 
    Alumnos  
    INNER JOIN  
    dblink('host=ip_del_host dbname=Personal user=tu_usuario password=tu_contraseña', '
        SELECT
          Nombre_Docente,
          Rfc_Docente,
          Curp_Docente
        FROM Docente
        ') AS tabla2 (
            Nombre_Docente char(50),
            Rfc_Docente char(50),
            Curp_Docente char(50)
        ) ON alumnos.Nombre_Docente = tabla2.Nombre_Docente
```

Toma en cuenta que hay que poner la `ip` del servidor si esta en el mismo pon **su ip o 127.0.0.1 no 'localhost'**.

En esta parte:

```
       tabla2 (
                Nombre_Docente char(50),
                Rfc_Docente char(50),
                Curp_Docente char(50)
            )
```

Evita problemas y pon  los campos como están en la base original yo aquí asumo que son **char(50)**.

Comment: y con otras bases de datos? por ejemplo de SQL Server a DB2?